# M3U8 playback issues with Vimeo and JW Player

Tags: video, jwplayer, vimeo, m3u8

M3U8 streams which previously played back without issues have started to fail with "Cannot load M3U8: cross domain access denied" errors.

The video embed logic in our application hasn't changed, video playback worked without issues last week, this week it's failing. :/

Replacing the M3U8 URL in the embed with the equivalent Mobile, Standard or High def video playback URL from Vimeo resolves the issue but obviously means we can't utilise M3U8.

We're using JW Player 6.12 for playback, you can see the issue demonstrated on the following test page:

http://dev.ihasco.co.uk/client/video_playback_test

Comment: are you using it in web or mobile

Comment: Try bypassing the dns server and you will be able to play m3u8 url.

Comment: @war_Hero I'm testing on a desktop device.

Comment: @MayankAgarwal sorry can you clarify what you mean? Replacing the Vimeo player domain with the IP doesn't seem to make any odds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M3U8 files from Vimeo use 302 re-directs, which our Flash HLS implementation does not support.

Comment: Yup, seems that's the crux of the problem, last week though this all worked without issue so I suspect something at Vimeo changed to enforce HTTPS for HLS but the implementation doesn't quite yet seem complete, i.e. the .ts segments are still delivered over HTTP. :/

Comment: Ah, right. That is always an issue when using a 3rd party, since they can change things which will break certain implementations.

Comment: Fortunately we already had JW Platform set up as a fallback. :)

Comment: If anyone needs it here's a M3U8 URL parser which you can use to mitigate the issue: https://gist.github.com/nathanpitman/5f59edd56715c5f4f68d

Answer (score 3):

If you update the player url that you are using to https, it should work. In that case it will do a 302 redirect to the actual HLS manifest.

Comment: Yes, switching the page delivering the player, the player and the Vimeo URL to HTTPS seems to resolve the playback issue. Unfortunately at this time the HLS segments (the .ts files) are still delivered over HTTP so that then forces the page back to mixed HTTP/HTTPS. Does work though! :)

Comment: @NathanPitman we're working with our CDN to get those enabled as well.

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks Brad!

Comment: Any further update on this Brad... how are you guys getting on with the move to a complete HTTPS delivery? :)

Comment: @NathanPitman we've started rolling it out, but no word on how long it's going to take. Hopefully no more than a month or so.

Comment: Great to hear. Looking forward to our content being delivered entirely over HTTPS. :)